# where does 'Service Login' take place in WPF MVVM architecture?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, model

I have a WPF application, and I need to make it show a 'Login' window on startup, and then connect to a WCF service with credentials passed from the user.

Question is - where does the actual 'client.Open()' happen ?

in the ViewModel or in the Model ?

I think it should happen in a seperate class, but should be called by the ViewModel or the Model.

Which one is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi yes I totally misunderstood your question am sorry for that . Its like When user click Login button on UI ,Corresponding to that Command of that Button is fired and ViewModel method for Login is invoked that method further Calls the Clientside Service class(Model) method which further calls ServerSide Service class method which further calls BLL method Which further calls Repository method of Login.The chain is like View=> VM => ClientSideService=>ServerSideService=>BLL=>Repository. However you can skip ClientSide Service if you want to or can call ServerSide Service directly from ViewModel.Answer of "but should be called by the ViewModel or the Model?" is that they are called Model.I hope this will help

Comment: great. So you are saying that the Client-side service class should be in the 'Model' assembly...

Comment: and one more thing - say I want to have a continuous loop that sends a 'heartbeat' to the WCF service - would this continuous loop (in a different thread) be in the 'Model' ?

Answer (score 0):

hi if i have not mis interpreted your question you can do it as

```
   public partial class App : Application
{
    void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // Application is running
        // Process command line args
        bool startMinimized = false;
        for (int i = 0; i != e.Args.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (e.Args[i] == "/StartMinimized")
            {
                startMinimized = true;
            }
        }

        // Create main application window, starting minimized if specified
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        if (startMinimized)
        {
            mainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        }
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

and in xaml bind StartUp event of application

```
<Application
```

xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  x:Class="SDKSample.App"
  Startup="App_Startup" />

All this happen in App class . First Main method is called then the instance of App class is created and then Run method off App is called and this Run method fires the Application_Startup event I hope this will help.

Comment: I am afraid you have misunderstood my question. I need the WPF app to connect to a WCF service. The WPF app is in Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) architecture. Where does the code that connects to the service go ? In the 'Login' window's 'ViewModel' class or in it's 'Model' class ?